# sort a dictionary by the first letter of its keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I wrote a code that reads a whole DNA genome and returns a dictionary o all the 8-primers with their locations, i want to loop through this dictionary and sort these codons into 4 other dictionaries based on the letter they start with A,T,G and C.
But I couldn't figure out how to check the first letter of each key.

This is my code:

```
"""
Generating all the possible 8-codon primers.
saving them in a text file with their locations.
"""

import csv
##MAIN FUNCTION:
def k_mer(Text, k):
    dictionary = {}
    for i in range (len(Text) - k + 1):
        if(Text[i: i+k] in dictionary):
            dictionary[Text[i: i+k]].append(i)
        else:
            dictionary[Text[i: i+k]] = [i]
    return dictionary

##INPUT:
# open the file with the original sequence
myfile = open('Vibrio_cholerae.txt')

# set the file to the variable Text to read and scan
Text = myfile.read()
result = k_mer(Text.strip(), 8)

with open("result.txt","w") as f:
    from collections import Counter
    wr = csv.writer(f,delimiter=":")
    wr.writerows(Counter(result).items())
```

[image: here is a picture of the result dictionary that i want to sort by letter.]

Comment: `key[0]` is the first letter of `key`.

Comment: You should be able to use `itertools.groupby()` for this.

Comment: Could we see a sample of the text file you're reading? The problem itself sounds relatively trivial, but your question needs to have a few more details.

Comment: So, do you want `dct['A']['ACTGGTCA'] = 7` if that entry started at character 7?  You're looking at every character, including overlaps.  Is that correct?

Comment: @TimRoberts not exactly, i only want to check it the first letter of the codon starts with an A, without looking at the other letter in the same line.

Comment: @BenY i edited the post and added a picture of the result dictionary which i want to sort by the first letter of its keys

Comment: @Barmar i tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure you are sorting, rather than partitioning. What do these 4 separate dictionaries contain? Just 4 separate dictionaries with the respective contents of the original dictionary, partitioned by the first letter?

Comment: @BenY exactly, yes maybe partitioning is more accurate, i want to creat 4 seperate dictionaries based on the first letter of the keys.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given your `dictionary`, it's just this.  It's not a complicated problem.

```
groupby = {'A':{}, 'C':{}, 'G':{}, 'T':{} }
for k,v in dictionary.items():
    groupby[k[0]][k] = v
```